# How to validate domain user credentials across domains using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I need to validate domain user credentials across domains within the same network. For example domain user account is created on "Domain1", but I need to verify this user account from a computer C1 that is joined to "Domain2".
I am able to validate successfully by using DC IP address, but for this I need to find out DC IP adress of domain2 from the computer C1 which I couldn't do programmatically.

Is there any other way to validate domain user credentials?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dns.GetHostEntry for acquiring the IP address.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

What API have you been using for auth - Was it the LogonUser function ?

Comment: I used ValidateCredentials() of PrincipalContext class.

Comment: Dns.GetHostEntry() doesn't help to get DC list of a domain